# Running Python script from HTML and updating DIV with the output

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyserial

The project I'm working consists in reading the RFID tag using the RFID Reader connected to the Arduino and then sending the ID via Serial Port (USB connection). This only works when I click a button on a HTML page.

This first part is fully operational, I have a Python script that sends a command to Arduino, reads the Serial Port and print on screen the response. It takes about 5 to 10 seconds to connect to Arduino, read the RFID tag and send its value back.

```
import time
import serial
import cgi

comport = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

PARAM_CARACTER = 'a'

time.sleep(1.5) # Entre 1.5s a 2s

comport.write(PARAM_CARACTER.encode())

VALUE_SERIAL = ""

while (len(VALUE_SERIAL) < 9):
    VALUE_SERIAL = comport.read(11)

#f = open("serial_data.txt","w")
#f.write(VALUE_SERIAL)
#f.close()

print "<p>" + VALUE_SERIAL + "</p>"

comport.close()
```

My problem is: how do I run this script from a HTML page, using PHP or JavaScript, to append this `VALUE_SERIAL` value to a DIV when I click a button?

I've already tried some codes I found on web, but none of them executes the Python file correctly.

Comment: You run Python on the server, not in the web browser. You use Ajax to communicate back and forth between the server and the web browser.

Comment: @kainaw I didn't know that. Thank you. Do you know any way to access the serial port on the client side? It's a small setup with one server and two or three clients. Only one client is connected to Arduino.

Comment: @cfranklin You will need to drop the web browser requirement. Web browsers are heavily sandboxed. You can't access much of a computer hardware in any way. If you rewrite this using a proper client, you can still talk over port 80 (HTTP) if you like. Python has libraries that do HTTP protocol for you, so you can just make a request and get the result all in Python.

Comment: Got it, @kainaw. I'm thinking about writing two versions for my application: a web based one and an executable ( `.exe` ) one. This last one will be used in one PC to read the Arduino data and register it to the database, since the other PCs only access the data from the database and it can be done via web. Anyway, thank you for your help.